# How to display integers in TextView using a for loop

Tags: android

How can i display integers inside this loop? When i run this code it only display one value.

**Sample:**

```
input1 = 4
input2 = 7 
Display: 4, 5 ,6 ,7
```

But my code below displays only 7.

```
public View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int inputFirst = Integer.parseInt(etTxt1.getText().toString());
        int inputSec = Integer.parseInt(etTxt2.getText().toString());
        for (int i = inputFirst; i <= inputSec; i++){
            tView.setText(i); ;
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have the comma in between, just get what's already in your `TextView` and add to it the new value.

```
public View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int inputFirst = Integer.parseInt(etTxt1.getText().toString());
        int inputSec = Integer.parseInt(etTxt2.getText().toString());
        for (int i = inputFirst; i <= inputSec; i++){
            tView.setText(tView.getText().toString()+" "i);
        }

    }
};
```

If you need the numbers to be comma-separated then the easiest way would be to construct an array of your numbers than print them using a join :

```
public View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        int inputFirst = Integer.parseInt(etTxt1.getText().toString());
        int inputSec = Integer.parseInt(etTxt2.getText().toString());
        for (int i = inputFirst; i <= inputSec; i++){
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        tView.setText(TextUtils.join(",",numbers));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to set Integer value in textview

***First***

`textview_1.setText(String.valueOf(i));`

***second***

`textview_1.setText(Integer.toString(i));`

***third***

`textview_1.setText("" + i);`

This is my code to display integer value in textview using for loop

**Code**

```
mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int inputFirst = Integer.parseInt(edit_1.getText().toString());
            int inputSec = Integer.parseInt(edit_2.getText().toString());
            Log.e("check_input", ":--" + inputFirst + "==" + inputSec);

            for (int i = inputFirst; i <= inputSec; i++) {
                textview_1.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                Log.e("check_value", "" + i);
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public View.OnClickListener buttonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int[] input = new int[2];
        input[0] = Integer.parseInt(etTxt1.getText().toString());
        input[1] = Integer.parseInt(etTxt2.getText().toString());
        for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++){
            tView.setText(String.valueOf(input[i]));
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Hi sir , im not using array here. I just want to display from 1-10. But in my code it only display the second input. Bdw, your code still displays 1 value and its 10

Comment: Example in input1 = 6 then input2 =10, it Displays 6, 7 ,8 ,9 ,10.